# Condition for association Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

There's a way to condition something to an associative table of ActiveRecord?

I retrieve `segments` this way:

```
@segments = Segment.all
```

But, a `Segment` `has_many` `products`. See:

**models/product.rb:**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :segment, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**models/segment.rb:**

```
class Segment < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :products
end
```

The problem is: I just want to retrieve products whose its status is equals to `1`. I can condition something like this using `where` on `Segment` model, but how can I achieve this for `products`?

### What I already tried

I found a solution. Take a look:

```
@segments = Segment.find(:all, include: :products, conditions: {products: {status: 1}})
```

It worked, but I think the code can be better.

### Why I think the code can be better

Well, why should I use `include: :products` if the association is already live within the models? We're associating things through the model and I'm sure that is something near to enough.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few tips, that might help you.

For easy naming purposes, I am considering the `status==1` as being `active`. Of course I have no idea what it means in your specific case.

```
class Product

  ACTIVE=1

  def self.active
    where(status: ACTIVE)
  end

end
```

Now you write something like:

```
segment.products.active
```

and this will return only the active products for the given segment.

The solution you found, which will retrieve all segments with (active) products, could be written differently as follows:

```
Segment.includes(:products).where(products: {status: 1})
```

Now, why so elaborate: this actually translates to a sql query, so you have to be a little more explicit about it.

Comment: Thank you, @nathanvda. Actually, all answers were helpful to me, but yours one sounds more consistent. I think it's more DRY. And more: you opened my mind for different things that we can do with models. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

```
Segment.joins(:products).where("products.status = 1")
```

You can also use includes instead of joins. But rails will convert it into a join internally since you are using the products table attribute in the query

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job - and it's compatibile with AREL syntax:

```
@segments = Segment.joins(:products).where(products: {status: 1})
```

It's quite different that solution with `include` (or `includes`, as it would be Rails 3/4), because it generates query with `INNER JOIN`, while `includes` generates `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Also, `includes` is usually used for eager loading associated records, not for queries with `JOIN`.

Comment: The same solution by other syntacsis. Not answer the question.

Comment: @Chumakoff: technically `joins != includes`, but conceptually the same with different syntax indeed.

Answer (score 1):

If you only ever want those with a status of 1

```
class Segment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products, :conditions => { :status => 1 }
end
```

In rails 3 or

```
class Segment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products, -> { where status: 1 }
end
```

In rails 4

Obviously can use status: true if it's a boolean

Then

```
@segments = Segment.includes(:products)
```

Comment: I am assuming you want to eager load the products though, if you just want segments that have products with a status of one then use one of the other solutions

Answer (score 1):

The association **has_many :products** makes it possible to use **include: :products** in your scope. Therefore you shouldn't doubt in your solution. It is right, and it is just the same as  solutions presented in the other answers but by other syntacsis.